# Magento2.1 configurable price

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, price

I have a custom theme, in configurable products when i choose variation price doesn't change. Which files should i override?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below files :

Overriding `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work